# Creating custom XML widgets for Android UI

Tags: refactoring, android, android-xml

I'm trying to encapsulate certain layouts that I've made, to help me dry up my android xml ui files.

I have the following code:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/text_view_small"
                android:id="@+id/time"></TextView>
            <TextView
                style="@style/text_view_small"
                android:id="@+id/number_of_worlds">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I want to simply convert it to the following

```
<DoubleTextView></DoubleTextView>
```

Once done I want to be able to use the "widgit" in other xml files.
Are there any particular resources or examples that I can look at to help me figure out how to do this?